# Odoo 14 update/load language during (automatic) module update

Tags: localization, odoo, odoo-14

I know how to add translations to my custom module (with .po-files in \i18n-folder). I also know how to force `Odoo.sh` to automatically update my custom module during build, with updating the version-number.
This works fine for data, views, and so on. But is doesn't seem to work for my translations. I always have to go to Developer-mode -> Settings -> Translations -> Activate/update.

How can I also automate the update of my translations?

**EDIT:**
I've found the post_init_hook, and tried the following:

```
# coding: utf-8

from odoo import api, fields, models, _, SUPERUSER_ID

def install_languages(cr, registry):
    """ Post init function """
    env = api.Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {})

    # install DE language
    lang_de = env['base.language.install'].create({'lang': 'de_DE', 'overwrite': False})
    env['base.language.install'].lang_install(lang_de)
```

The line `env['base.language.install'].create({'lang': 'de_DE', 'overwrite': False})` however, generates a build-warning with `Transient module states were reset`, and then a build-error occurs `Failed to load registry` and `Failed to load database...`.

**EDIT 2:**
the error had another cause and is fixed.
the post_init gives no error, but also does not update the language.

Comment: That's probably a question you should ask Odoo :-)

Comment: @CZoellner thank you, I asked them also, but currently no answer

Comment: @BerDev Did you ever manage to get this done? I'm automating environment creation for tests and I couldn't get this part right....

Comment: @LFLFM we've migrated to Odoo 15 later, and currently works fine with updating version-no in manifest.